# Add name to set_values using Rvest

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape [this](https://demo.glpi-project.org/) website, I have written a code for login using `rvest`, but every time the page refreshes the name of the form changes.

```
library(rvest)

loginpage <- "https://demo.glpi-project.org/"

pagesession <- html_session(loginpage)

pageform <- html_form(pagesession)[[1]]

formfill <- set_values(pageform, fielda5bd99dcd2eaa8 = "****", 
fieldb5bd99dcd2eaad = "****")

successlogin <- submit_form(pagesession,formfill)
```

`fielda5bd99dcd2eaa8` & `fieldb5bd99dcd2eaad` are the name of the input field which changes every time it refreshes.

right now I am changing the name field every time I run the script

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this is enough of a hint to get you in the right direction:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(dplyr)

httr::GET(
  "https://demo.glpi-project.org/"
) -> res

pg <- httr::content(res)

form <- html_nodes(pg, "form")
inputs <- html_nodes(form, "input")

data_frame(
  id = html_attr(inputs, "id"),
  name = html_attr(inputs, "name"),
  value = html_attr(inputs, "value")
)
## # A tibble: 6 x 3
##   id             name                value                           
##   <chr>          <chr>               <chr>                           
## 1 login_name     fielda5bd9bf41b7af9 NA                              
## 2 login_password fieldb5bd9bf41b7afe NA                              
## 3 NA             auth                local                           
## 4 login_remember fieldc5bd9bf41b7aff NA                              
## 5 NA             submit              Post                            
## 6 NA             _glpi_csrf_token    ea1aff0b53753e14a76077bd77fb21c2
```

Comment: Thanks sir, but i am not able to combine your code to mine i am getting unknown field error,coz i have to set values like this `formfill <- set_values(inputs, df$name[1] = "****", df$name[2] = "****")`, and i think this is not correct coz you cant put variable in the place of default argument...can you please tell me how can i combine your code with mine...

Comment: I'd suggest not relying on `rvest` and exploring how to use `httr::GET()` & `httr::POST()` to do form posting & web app instrumentation more idiomatically.